# DIV - Alternate background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Instead of implementing a slider plugin, I'd like to use CSS/jquery to alternate background images of a DIV (fadein/fadeout or slide effect).
Currently my code is as below:

HTML

```
<div class="block backpic">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {

    display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.backpic {
    height: 638px;
    background-image: url(../images/picture1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What should I do to alternate picture1 with a second picture?
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Good point, have edited the code. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use jQuery to fade the element out, than change it's `background-image` property, then fade back in again:

```
$('.block').fadeOut(300, function(){

  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(path/to/other/image.jpg)')

  $(this).fadeIn(300);

});
```

If you're wanting a slideshow-like cycling of the animation, use a JavaScript `setInterval` method to have the code repeat itself after a certain number of milliseconds:

```
var images = [

  'path/to/image1.jpg',
  'path/to/image2.jpg',
  'path/to/image3.jpg'

];

var index = 0;

setInterval(change_up, 1000);

function change_up(){

  index = (index + 1 < images.length) ? index + 1 : 0;

  $('.block').fadeOut(300, function(){

    $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+ images[index] + ')')

    $(this).fadeIn(300);

  });
}
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SXsbL/1/)

Comment: Thanks Shennan. Actually I should have been a little bit more specific. I have updated my question accordingly and I tried to applied you code (I replaced '.block" by .'backpic' but without success. Would you know why? Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps because you need to use the same syntax as the CSS for the background image. Specifically the `url()` directive. Have updated code and provided a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Shennnan. Looking at your jsfiddle the images just fadein/out 1x. Is it possible to fade-in / fade-out constantly to give a kind of "slider" effect? Thanks

Comment: @Greg I feel that may be a little out of the scope of this question, but I've updated my answer with some code that will do what you're asking. See the fiddle for an example.

Answer (score 0):

try using even and odd selectors

```
    .block:nth-child(odd) {
background-image:
 height: 638px;
    background-image: url(../images/picture1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
background-image:
 height: 638px;
    background-image: url(../images/pictureNew.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a core slider class

```
.slider{
   opacity:1
   -webkit-transition:opacity 500ms;
   -moz-transition:opacity 500ms;
   -ms-transition:opacity 500ms;
   transition:opacity 500ms;
}

.hideSlide{
   opacity:0
}
```

This will cause the fade of opacity. Then you can change your opacity with the hide slide class and when it is transparent change the background image. Then remove the hide slide class and it will fade back in.

Alternatively you could have a bunh of divs laid on top of one another fading out at increasing lengths 500ms 1000ms, 1500ms etc. to expose them to the viewer.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. However not sure how to implement this? How would the html code look like? Also where would you set the 100% width and background-size: cover? Thanks

Comment: your html would look something like this

    <section class='slider'></section>

    OR

    <div class='slider'></div>

all of your CSS would go into the slider class. The only thing the hideSlide class would do is hide the slide.